# Connecting javascript to java with java as backend

Tags: javascript, java, html, applet

I am trying a simple web application using html, javascript and java. HTML and javascript are part of the frontend and java forms the backend. I am using applets. I don't want to use JSP or JSF as my current requirement says that I need to use HTML and javascript only. I am getting the following error.

[image]

I got this code from an online source. My code is as below:

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="liveconnect.js"> </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="showProgrammer()">
   <applet id="app" code="LauncherApplet" height="1" width="1" MAYSCRIPT></applet> 
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="name"/></td>
  </tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="age"/></td>
  </tr>
    <td>Programming Language(PHP,Java or Python)</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="language"/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" onclick="processProgrammer()" value="click"/>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function Programmer(name,age,language){
  this.name=name;
  this.age=age;
  this.language=language;
 }
 function showProgrammer(){
 try{
   var programmer=app.getProgrammer(); //app is the id of applet tag which refers to the applet instance.
   var data="Name= "+programmer.name+",Age= "+programmer.age+",Language= "+programmer.language;
   alert(data);
 }
 catch(e){
   alert(e);
  }
 }
 function processProgrammer(){
 try{
   var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
   var age=document.getElementById("age").value;
   var language=document.getElementById("language").value;
   var programmer=app.getProgrammer();
   var myprog=new Programmer(name,age,language);
   programmer.setData(myprog);
   var advice=programmer.getAdvice();
   alert(advice);
  }
  catch(e){
   alert(e);
  }
 }
```

Applet:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class LauncherApplet extends Applet{
  public Programmer getProgrammer(){
    return new Programmer();
 }
```

}

The main java file:

```
import netscape.javascript.*;
public class Programmer {
  public String name="Programmer1";
  public String age="20";
  public String language="Java";
  public void setData(JSObject js){
  try{
    this.name=((String)js.getMember("name")).toLowerCase();
    this.age=((String)js.getMember("age")).toLowerCase();
    this.language=((String)js.getMember("language")).toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Name= "+name+",Age= "+age+",language= "+language);
 }
 catch(JSException e){System.out.println(e);}
}
public String getAdvice(){
  String advice="";
  switch(language){
   case "php":
     advice=name+", you should definitely try out CodeIgniter.";
     break;
   case "java":
     advice=name+", you should definitely try out JavaServer Faces.";
     break;
   case "python":
     advice=name+", you should definitely try out Django.";
     break;
   default:
     advice="You language of choice is not any one of PHP, Java or Python";
  }
  return advice;
 }
}
```

The java files have been compiled successfully. No errors. Please tell me what mistake I am making.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"HTML and javascript are part of the frontend and java forms the backend. I am using applets."* That doesn't make sense. Applets are UI. If you're using Java only in the backend, you don't want to use applets.

Comment: use HTML, Javascript (or jquery) to send ajax commands to a servlet or webservice.

Comment: Moreover, applets are dead. Chrome no longer supports the NPAPI that the Java plugin requires to work in the browser, Firefox is dropping support for it as well, and Edge doesn't support applets either.

Comment: Applets are dead - yay

Comment: Mozilla provides something called LiveConnect. This technology allows javascript to connect to java and viceversa. I've just tried this. You can see in the `Programmer.java`, the import statement has `netscape.javascript`. This package helps create the connection. This technology requires an applet to be launched.

Answer (score -1):

You could possibly use DWR(Direct Web Routing) technology. This is simply a Ajax functions..

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html

This would possibly help you.

Comment: My goodness DWR still exists - must be 10 years since I used it.

Comment: Hmm, seems to belong to a world before Ajax